# How to send a vector of strings to a function

Tags: rust, vector, arguments

I am trying to learn Rust. I am trying to send a vector of strings to a function. I am using following code:

```
fn myfn(svect: vec![String]) -> &'static str{
  "A string will be created from svect and returned."
}
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
error: expected type, found `<[_]>::into_vec(#[rustc_box] ::alloc::boxed::Box::new([String]))`
   --> src/main.rs:196:16
    |
196 | fn myfn(svect: vec![String]) -> &'static str{
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                |
    |                expected type
    |                in this macro invocation
    |                this macro call doesn't expand to a type
    |
    = note: this error originates in the macro 
`$crate::__rust_force_expr` which comes from 
the expansion of the macro `vec` (in Nightly 
builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I tried using `Vec`, `Vec!`, `String::String` but all give errors.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: "I tried using Vec, Vec!, String::String but all give errors." How did you try using them and what errors did they yield? `vec!` is a macro which expands to an expression, it creates a new Vec then fills it with the provided values, so what you wrote makes no sense, why did you think it'd work? Also the intent signaled by your signature seems rather optimistic, have you read the book?

Comment: Try `svect:Vec<String>` instead of `svect: vec![String]`. `vec!` is a macro invocation returning a value of type E.g. `Vec`. vec!["str"] will return a value of type `Vec<&str>`.

Comment: `svect:Vec<String>`  works. What is the difference?

Comment: @Masklinn : I am not able to understand what you mean by "intent signalled by your signature seems optimistic".

Comment: Your function returns `&'static str`, which is a borrow which never ends, which is not normally a thing you create dynamically from runtime values. It tends to be associated with string literals.

Comment: "What is the difference?" that they have nothing in common? `Vec` is a type, not a macro, it's also a *generic* type (you need to specify what it's a vector of), so `Vec<String>` is the type for a vector of (owned) strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
fn process_strings(strings: Vec<String>) 
{
    //Do something
}

fn main() 
{
    let strings = vec!["Hello".to_string(), "world".to_string(), "!".to_string()];
    process_strings(strings);
}
```

You can also use slices:

```
fn process_strings(strings: &[&str]) 
{
    //Do something
}

fn main() 
{
    let strings = vec!["Hello", "world", "!"];
    let string_slices: Vec<&str> = strings.iter().map(|s| s.as_str()).collect();
    process_strings(&string_slices);
}
```

Comment: Will `fn process_strings(strings: Vec<String>) `  be ok if `let strings = vec!["Hello", "world", "!"];` is sent to it?

Comment: No, beacuse `let strings = vec!["Hello", "world", "!"];` is `Vec<&str>` not a `Vec<String>` type. They are two different types